# how to set csrf token for allowed list of websites

Tags: django, webserver, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I am having two servers says domain name "example.com" and "demo.com". I did all my project stuff in "demo.com". But I want sign up page of "demo.com" also in  "example.com" home page where user is redirected after POST data to "demo.com" server whether he/she give correct or wrong information.

I got csrf error. When I gave exempt csrf token. It worked fine, which i dont want. Can someone help me in this without using csrf exempt. or csrf exempt for only two servers i.e. "example.com" and "demo.com" (Allowed host list)

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: That's...  not how CSRF works.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible and as @Daniel mentioned in comments thats not how it works. CSRF token will be generated by the server whenever user visits the page, everytime. And it's different everytime. When user submits the form, the server validates, whether it was same one which it sent or different.

You should also understand why CSRF protection exists in first place. For example, assume if a POST request on `stackoverflow.com/avi/delete` would delete my profile on SO.

Now if I visit a malicious site and it may have an innocent looking form asking for my name and email:

```
<form action="http://stackoverflow.com/avi/delete" method="post">
    Your name: <input type="text"><br>
    Your email: <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I am logged in SO and my session is valid and also, at the same time I submit above from the malicious site, my account will be deleted! Because browser will send the SO related cookies and SO server can identify them. But good guys at SO are clever. The page on SO, which has account deletion form, also includes a CSRF token. And this token will be generated everytime whenever user visits the page. And server validates it, if it is same then account will be deleted and if not, it will simply ignore the request.

Now, the malicious site cannot possibly know the CSRF token generated by SO. So, even if I submit the form, my account will be still safe on SO.

Now, in your case, what essentially you want is, a token to be generated from the Server A and you want to be validated by Server B. Now, you *can* actually use a same token everytime and so that Server B can validate it. But that defeats the whole purpose of CSRF tokens.